# How to plot Errors Over Time Graph in Jmeter?

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

Tried customizing user properties for JMeter dashboard and it didn't help. Which columns are used to plot error vs time from the results csv document ?
Tried Graph generator listener but unable to load previous test results for plotting.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart displays transactions with `success` and `failure` postfixes

   [image]
2. [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond/) displays all HTTP status codes over time (including erroneous ones)

   [image]
3. You can exclude successful results from the .jtl results file via [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/)

All above plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)